# How to turn ON auto-scroll on Windows 7 PC?

Tags: windows-7, windows, mouse, autohotkey, scrolling

I'm just getting familiar with the auto-scroll feature in my (Vivaldi) browser and I would like to use it everywhere. I know that laptops have this feature but I cannot find a way to enable on Windows 7 PC.

I'm using [MouseGestureL.ahk](http://hp.vector.co.jp/authors/VA018351/en/mglahk.html) [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) script, but I cannot set it up to this behaviour. So an AHK script could be the answer too.

Comment: https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/4899-autoscroll/

Comment: @user3419297 Seems to be useful, thanks. Do you know a script which makes it smooth?